# jQuery append value from textarea to input

Tags: jquery, input

While entering input in a Textarea I want the same text to append to an input, i.e. the input has a value of "http://www." and whatever I enter in the textarea I want to be appended to input's value.

Now it always adds the change to the change, e.g.:

(entering google.com in the textarea)
it adds:
g
go
goo
goog
etc.
which results in:
http://www.ggogoogoog... etc.

what am I doing wrong?

```js
var titleLink = "";
var url = $('#text2');
 
function inputLink(){  
  titleLink = $('#text1').val();
  console.log("changed: " + titleLink);
  var http = url.val(); 
  url.val(http + titleLink);
 };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10" oninput="inputLink()"></textarea> <br>
<input id="text2" type="text" value="http://www.">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `var http = url.val();`  this will get the updated input value each time you input .. So

you can use `var http = 'http://www.';` instead

```js
var titleLink = "";
var url = $('#text2');
 
function inputLink(){
  titleLink = $('#text1').val();  // get textarea value
  console.log("changed: " + titleLink);
  var http = 'http://www.';  // http is 'http://www.'
  url.val( http + titleLink); // append http + textarea value
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="text1" id="text1" cols="30" rows="10" oninput="inputLink()"></textarea> <br>
<input id="text2" type="text" value="http://www.">
```

Comment: then i can make it even a little slimmer:
function inputLink(){  
  titleLink = $('#text1').val();
  url.val("http://www." + titleLink);
 };

Comment: @Melvin in one line function inputLink(){url.val('http:// www.' + $('#text1').val()); }